# SpringBootTest support for running diffent SpringBoot Application Instances

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

With SpringBoot i can easily run the same Application as different instances with different configurations, for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"..."})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start(Application.class)
            .properties("notification.sender.app.name=SomeApp", "notification.this.app.name =AnotherApp", "server.port=${first.port:9010}").run(args);
        start(Application.class)
            .properties("first.app.name=AnotherApp", "second.app.name =SomeApp", "server.port=${second.port:9020}").run(args);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder start(Class<?>... sources) {
        return new SpringApplicationBuilder(sources).bannerMode(Mode.OFF);
    }
}
```

Which is terrific, specially for testing inter application communication stuff.

I am trying to achieve now the same with @SpringBootTest to run Unit Tests against the running Applications instances.

Probably easy, but I haven't got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I achieve this in Junit Tests with `@ContextConfiguration` and  `SpringRunner.class` as Test runner:

```
@Before
public void startUp() {
    someAppContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .properties("notification.app.name=SomeApp", "server.port=" + someAppPort).run();
    anotherAppContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .properties("notification.app.name=AnotherApp", "server.port=" + anotherAppPort).run();
}
```

where `someAppPort` and `anotherAppPort` is configured with `@Value`.

Comment: can you please explain this solution?

Comment: @afe You need a Spring Boot  Application.class  , annotated as you need it. In a Test Class , which you run with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), you a setup method startup() , which runs the same Spring Boot Application.class twice  on two different ports.

Comment: thanks for the details. What I always need in java is the name of the packages you import and the gradle/maven repository.